# How can I remove the border around a Graphviz graph file?

Tags: graph-theory, graphviz

Whenever I create a graph and render it to a PNG or PDF I get a border around my image.

This is the simplified dot code:

```
digraph graphname {
    graph [fontname = "Arial", fontsize=16, bgcolor=3, style=rounded, colorscheme=set39, labelloc=t, ranksep=0.5];
    node [fontname = "Arial", fontsize=12, style=filled, colorscheme=set39]; 
    label="The graph title"
    a -> b
    b -> c
    c -> b
}
```

[image: example PNG dot diagram showing the black border around the image] [image: example PDF dot diagram showing the black border around the image]

What option can I use to remove this border? I went through the [attribute list](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html) but could not find an option that specifies the border color or thickness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after I asked this question I stumbled upon a (seemingly unrelated) fix: it's the `colorscheme=set39` option of the graph that does this.

According to the documentation of the [`color`](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:color) attribute, colors can be set using the `"/schemename/colorname"` syntax, so I've changed the `colorscheme` option to `x11` (the default), but set `bgcolor="/set39/3"` effectively having the same color. The border is now gone.

```
digraph graphname {
    graph [fontname = "Arial", fontsize=16, bgcolor="/set39/3", style=rounded, colorscheme=x11, labelloc=t, ranksep=0.5];
    node [fontname = "Arial", fontsize=12, style=filled, colorscheme=set39]; 
    label="The graph title"
    a -> b
    b -> c
    c -> b
}
```

This is the PNG without border:
[image]

And here's the PDF:
[image]

A proper way to configure that border is still welcome though.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the mentioned "I stumbled upon a (seemingly unrelated) fix"? I found the description of the colorscheme (https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:colorscheme), but where did you find the a reference to / definition of  "set39" ?

Comment: @albert added. It's described in the 2nd paragraph of the color attribute documentation.

Comment: Bummer. I could not get this hack to work for me. I am using a pastel scheme and tried to override the bgcolor with /x11/white to no avail.

Comment: @mattsmith321 what is not working for you? Do you get an error? Does the border still show? If you can post the link to a snippet that has the issue I can take a look if you want.